# How do I exclude a pattern with a lookbehind that is in front of another pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

How do I not capture or detect matches if the regex pattern precedes this regex pattern  `r"(?<=\s)|^)dont\s*"`

This is the pattern that you want to use to exclude matches. It correctly uses a lookbehind `"(?<=\s|^)dont"` to check for a space or the start of the string before the word `"dont"`. This ensures that the word "dont" is not preceded by any characters other than spaces or the start of the string.

Basically, what I am looking to achieve is that if there is a `"dont"` before the original pattern that has a space `"\s"` or the beginning of the string `"^"`, then it does not detect the match and therefore does not capture the capture group either.

```py
import re

#example 1 with capture, because it does not match this part of the pattern (?<=\s)|^)
#input_text = "I think Idont like a lot red apples" 
#example 2 not capture
input_text = "I think I dont like a lot red apples"

interests_match = re.search(r"(?:like\s*a\s*lot\s+(.+?)", input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)

if interests_match: print(interests_match.group(1))
```

The correct output for each example:

```
"red apples" #example 1
None #example 2
```

Comment: If it's directly preceded, just use a *lookbehind* and also you can shorten `((?<=\s)|^)` to `(?<!\S)` so the regex can be something like [`(?<!(?<!\S)dont\s)\blike\s*a\s*lot\s+(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/AslEYw/2) (we don't know yet what you want to capture, I changed `.+?` to `.+`)

Comment: @bobblebubble I really like that solution you proposed. It has worked for me without the need to resort to a double condition that would complicate things if the regex pattern became more complex than the simplified one in the example of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
r"(?:(?:^|\s)dont.*)|(?:like\s*a\s*lot\s+)(.+)"
```

The pattern on the left side of the second `|` will skip the rest of the line if it has `^dont` or `\sdont` in it, so that the `(.+)` will not capture anything.

Note: You will need to check that the group 1 match exists so that you don't get an error.

Comment: The problem is that `(?<=\s|^)dont` must **NOT** appear before the rest of the pattern, that is, there can **NOT** be a `"dont"` string preceded by a whitespace `\s` or the beginning of the string `^`, and then there will be the rest of the regex pattern. And **in case it is NOT, that is when it performs the match.**